# PyCharm: lost ipython kernel window

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

This is really silly, but it's driving me nuts!

Normally when I run ipython notebook through pycharm, the first time I click on the 'play' button to run a cell, PyCharm asks me if I want to start the kernel. When I say yes, it gives me a nice kernel window that shows me output from commands and errors.

I really like this feature for debugging, but somehow it went away. PyCharm no longer asks if I would like to start the kernel, and I no longer can find the kernel window. My notebook is still running just fine, so the ipython kernel must be started somewhere.

Can someone please tell me how to view the kernel window?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to JetBrains support. This is a known issue with Python 2.7.9 via Anaconda (maybe just with Anaconda in general, they did not specify). They said it will be fixed with the next release, which should be coming out in the next few days.

Comment: PyCharm EAP 5 142.5084 23.09.2015 seems still broken, Python 2.7.10

Comment: Yeah, it still has the bug. I've found that if I go into settings and delete any information under the ipython settings (such as an ip address) and restart pycharm, that resolves it temporarily.